# What is wrong with arithmetic operation

Tags: java

I know perhaps is stupid question but I don 't understand what is wrong in the following operation:

```
 value = 8.14
 double netvalue = value / (1 + 23 / 100);
```

and the result is:

```
 netvalue = 8.14
```

Comment: AFAIK everyone does integer division in primary school, but nearly everyone forgets about it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Division has precedence over addition, so
`1 + 23 / 100` is evaluated as `1 + (23/100)` which is `1 + 0` (`23/100` is 0 since it is int division, so the result is an int), so you are dividing `value` by 1.

You can change `23` to `23.0` to achieve floating point division :

```
double netvalue = value / (1 + 23.0 / 100);
```

Or you can simply divide by 1.23 :

```
double netvalue = value / 1.23;
```

Answer (score 2):

Let understand this

```
double netvalue = value / (1 + 23 / 100);
```

the first  thing evaluated is `23/100 gives 0`

and `1+ 0 = 1`

and finally `double netvalue =  8.14/1; gives  8.14`